# Visual Basic - Array loses values outside For Each loop

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

I have a slight coding problem with an array that looses all values outside of a For Each loop. I've tried numerous solutions. I can see all the data correctly inside the loop (tried looping the whole array inside the loop too, contains all values), but as soon as it exits, the array is empty.

Tried declaring the temporary array outside the sub as public too. Any ideas would be appreciated. At the end of my rope here :-(

PS: HSarray is declared as friend in a module.

Public Class highscoreForm

```
Private TempArray(0) As Integer

Private Sub ScoreGet()

    Dim Counter As Integer = 0

    'Oppretter textfieldParser, Leser alle linjer fra tekstfil inn i array
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                    FileIO.TextFieldParser(ScoreFile)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow

                    'Øker størrelsen på Array per linje / Kjøring av løkke
                    If Counter > 0 Then

                        'Skriver verdi til siste index i array
                        Counter = Counter + 1
                        ReDim Preserve TempArray(Counter)

                        TempArray(Counter) = currentField


                        'Hvis løkke kjører for første gang, skriv verdi til index 0, fortsett    
                    ElseIf Counter < 1

                        TempArray(Counter) = currentField
                        Counter = Counter + 1

                    End If


                Next
                'TempArray stops containing data here----WHY????


            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
                        FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("OBS! Noe gikk galt ved uthenting av high score")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using


    'Sorterer array etter data-størrelse - Noe kødd her!!
    TempArray.Sort(TempArray)
    TempArray.Reverse(TempArray)



    'Skriver de 5 første (og største) verdiene i temp-array til liste shared array i modul
    Array.Copy(TempArray, HSarray, 5)




    'Sletter innhold
    'Erase TempArray
    'ReDim TempArray(0)

End Sub
```

Comment: You really don't need to be using the likes of `ReDim` with .NET - take a look at things like [`List(Of T)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb)

Comment: I'll look into this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The array variable must be declared at the procedure level. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx. *You can use ReDim only at procedure level. Therefore, the declaration context for the variable must be a procedure; it can't be a source file, a namespace, an interface, a class, a structure, a module, or a block.* I would try declaring it at the procedure level again, but this time without the size parameter.

```
Dim TempArray() As Integer
```

Then remove the `If counter > 0` and the entire `Else` clause so that it Redim each time through the loop.

Comment: A tried declaring it within the subroutine (as other, similar examples show). No luck.

Went with an ArrayList (which is slower, but dynamic). Worked like a charm :-)